# Как правильно расставить знаки препинания? (4)

Tags: пунктуация

*Если вы решили – "прямому посеву быть!" — и дело за техникой, которая поможет реализовать все преимущества технологии, предлагаем обратить внимание на бренд "Агро"*.
Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания в этом предложении?

Answer (score 1):

**Предложение нестандартное:** первое тире обозначает бессоюзную связь, а вот второе тире я бы заменила запятой, так как два тире с разным значением не рекомендуется использовать, а пауза здесь нужна.

**Если вы решили – "прямому посеву быть!,  и дело за техникой, которая поможет реализовать все преимущества технологии, предлагаем обратить внимание на бренд "Агро".**

**Варианты для сравнения:**

1) **Нет паузы и запятой** перед И, однородные условные придаточные:

Если вы выбрали прямой посев  и дело за техникой, которая поможет реализовать все преимущества технологии, предлагаем обратить внимание на бренд "Агро".

2) **Запятая** закрывает придаточное изъяснительное предложение:

Если вы решили, что "прямому посеву быть!", и дело за техникой, которая поможет реализовать все преимущества технологии, предлагаем обратить внимание на бренд "Агро".

Answer (score 1):

Восклицательный знак наводит на мысль об употреблении прямой речи.
Коммерческое предложение желательно акцентировать с помощью тире.

**Если вы решили: "Прямому посеву быть!" — и дело за техникой, которая поможет реализовать все преимущества технологии, — предлагаем обратить внимание на бренд "Агро".**